# Как добавить ссылку на открытый модаль фото fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="gallery"]', {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/fancybox/fancybox.umd.js"></script>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/fancybox/fancybox.css"
/>

<a class="gallery__item" data-fancybox="gallery" data-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682686581580-d99b0230064e?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" data-caption="Заголовок" data-source="тут будет ссылка 1">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682686581580-d99b0230064e?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D">
</a>
<a class="gallery__item" data-fancybox="gallery" data-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682686581580-d99b0230064e?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" data-caption="Заголовок" data-source="тут будет ссылка 1">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682686581580-d99b0230064e?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D">
</a>
<a class="gallery__item" data-fancybox="gallery" data-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682686581580-d99b0230064e?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" data-caption="Заголовок" data-source="тут будет ссылка 1">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682686581580-d99b0230064e?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D">
</a>
<a class="gallery__item" data-fancybox="gallery" data-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682686581580-d99b0230064e?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" data-caption="Заголовок" data-source="тут будет ссылка 1">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682686581580-d99b0230064e?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D">
</a>
```

как отображать значение data-source на открытом картинке в модальке (попап)